# How retrieve http delete method params in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

In an Angular 2 client app, I have added a parameter to the http.delete method's RequestOptions: (new RequestOptions({headers: this.headers, body: body})). Does anybody know if it's being stripped off on the server side in ServiceStack ? Alternatively, where it's stored in the server's Request object ?

Answer (score 0):

If the params added on the QueryString in `IRequest.QueryString`, if they're added as HTTP Headers in `IRequest.Headers`, body parameters should be populated on the Request DTO.

Check the Raw HTTP Request Headers to see how the parameters are sent in the HTTP Request.